# THREE.js / CSS2DRenderer code is correct but Label is unvisible

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I want to put a name tag on 3D Models.

I confirmed that the  exists through the console log, but it is not displayed on the screen.
Changing the z-index value does not work either.
here is my code.

<index.html>

```
  <body>
    <canvas id="three-canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
```

<main.css>

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
#three-canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.label {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #fde047;
  padding: 40px;
  /* font-family: sans-serif; */
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

<main.js>

```
/** Renderer */
const canvas = document.querySelector("#three-canvas");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 2 : 1);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

/** CSS2DRenderer */
const labelRenderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = "0px";
canvas.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);


/** Scene */
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

... 
(Light and Camera)
...

/**  Geometry */
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: "hotpink",
  shininess: 5,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
});

const test = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
test.position.set(1, 0.5, 1);
scene.add(test);

test.layers.enableAll();

const labelDiv = document.createElement("div");
labelDiv.className = "label";
labelDiv.textContent = "Label Text Here";
labelDiv.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

const labelText = new CSS2DObject(labelDiv);
labelText.position.set(1, 0, 0);
labelText.center.set(0, 1);
test.add(labelText);
labelText.layers.set(0);


/** play */
function draw() {
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(draw);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

/** Event */
window.addEventListener("resize", setSize);


draw();
```

1. I've also tried adding to the gltf model by using a container, but the label doesn't show up.

```
export class Player {
  constructor(info) {
    this.moving = false;

    info.gltfLoader.load(info.modelSrc, (glb) => {
      glb.scene.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
          child.castShadow = true;
        }
      });

      this.modelMesh = glb.scene.children[0];
      this.modelMesh.position.set(0, 0.3, 0);

      this.modelMesh.name = "player";

      this.modelMesh.layers.enableAll();

      const label = document.createElement("div");
      label.className = "label";
      label.textContent = "Label text here";

      const labelObj = new CSS2DObject(label);
      labelObj.position.set(3, 3, 0);

      const container = new THREE.Object3D();
      container.add(this.modelMesh);
      container.add(labelObj);
      container.position.copy(this.modelMesh.position);

      info.scene.add(container);

      this.actions = [];
      this.mixer = new AnimationMixer(this.modelMesh);
      this.actions[0] = this.mixer.clipAction(glb.animations[0]);
      this.actions[1] = this.mixer.clipAction(glb.animations[1]);
      this.actions[0].play();

      // Check if the label exists in the container
      const hasLabel = container.children.some(
        (child) => child instanceof CSS2DObject
      );

      if (hasLabel) {
        console.log(" Label Exists"); // This log is printed but the label is not visible
      } else {
        console.log("‍♀️ Nothing");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

2.I tried applying it to the cube in my code in the format of this example code, but the label did not appear. (https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label)

3. I tried changing the position value of the label and the text color/background color, but the result did not change.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

```
canvas.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement) [X]

document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement) [O]
```

and add this

labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = "none";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).